# AnyLogic: Is it possibile to multiple/sum/subtract/...respectively link two TableFunctions in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic, table-functions

I have two TableFunctions f1: arguments1 -> values1 and f2: arguments2 -> values2 given via their arguments[] and values[] arrays. I want to link them to a new TableFunction g, so that:
The arguments of g shall be: arguments1 + 0.5 * arguments2
The values of g shall be: min{values1, values2}.

Is there any way to implement it via code? I tried to do that, however, I always have the problem that when forming a cartesian product, duplicates will arise.

Comment: can you share the code you have, where you tried to implement this. It sounds more like a coding problem than an "AnyLogic" problem. Also just out of curiosity....you have asked 9 questions in the last month, and most of them have answers yet you have not accepted a single one... where non of them helpful in answering your questions or are you not aware of the functionality on SOF? Just checking ;-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your hint. I was not aware of this functionality and will mark the answers :D

Comment: Awesome! All is good! Also if you want to you can upvote an answer if you think it worthy ;-) 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, assuming you have 2 table functions of the same size called t2 and t4, and your new table function is newT:

You can do this on the startup of your simulation (note that i arbitrarily chose linear interpolation to the nearest value if out of range)

```
double [] values = new double[t2.getValues().length];
double [] arguments = new double[t2.getValues().length];

for(int i = 0; i<values.length;i++){
    arguments[i]=t2.getArguments()[i]+0.5*t4.getArguments()[i];
    values[i]=min(t2.getValues()[i],t4.getValues()[i]);
}
newT=new TableFunction( arguments, values, 
       TableFunction.INTERPOLATION_LINEAR, 1, TableFunction.OUTOFRANGE_NEAREST,
       0.0 );
```